# closest value and data frame index index of all data frame elements of a list

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list containing data frames:

```
test <- list()
test[[1]] <- data.frame(C1=c(0.2,0.4,0.5), C2=c(2,3.5,3.7), C3=c(0.3,4,5))
test[[2]] <- data.frame(C1=c(0.1,0.3,0.6), C2=c(3.9,4.3,8), C3=c(3,5.2,10))
test[[3]] <- data.frame(C1=c(0.4,0.55,0.8), C2=c(8.9,10.3,14), C3=c(7,8.4,11))
```

I´d like to get the line among all data frames lines inside this list which column (e.g.C2 in this example) has the closest value to each element in a vector "vec" (below), as well as the list index (1, 2 or 3 in this example) where it happened.

```
vector <- c(3, 14.4, 7, 0)
```

The desired answer would be something like:

```
list.index    line.number.in.df    C1  C2 C3
     1              2              0.4 3.5 4 
     3              3              0.8 14 11
     2              3              0.6  8 10
     1              1              0.2  2 0.3
```

I could manage to use lapply to get 10% of the problem solved for a single value, but couldn´t do it for a bunch of values (vector) besides getting all list elements dataframe lines where the closest value as found (not only a single line among all data frames),and could not get the corresponding list index as well, i.e.

```
value <- 3
lapply(test, function(x) x[which.min(abs(value-x$C2)),])
```

Result I got:

```
[[1]]
  C1  C2 C3
2 0.4 3.5  4

[[2]]
  C1  C2 C3
1 0.1 3.9  3

[[3]]
  C1  C2 C3
1 0.4 8.9  7
```

Would anyone be so kind and patient to get me further on this?

Thanks in advance and Happy New Year.

Comment: I don't understand the desired output. For instance, taking a look at `C1=c(0.2,0.4,0.5)`, 0.4 is not the number which is the most frequently closest to all values in `vector <- c(3, 14.4, 7, 0)`, but rather 0.5. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Dion . In fact, the first elements from C1, C2 and C3 will form the 1st line of each data frame in the list.

Comment: `   C1  C2  C3`
`1 0.2 2.0 0.3`
`2 0.4 3.5 4.0`
`3 0.5 3.7 5.0`
'
In this example, I´m looking for the closest element of each vecrot element (fiset element is 3) in  the second column of this 1st list data frame ($C2). The corresponding line is  `0.4 3.5 4.0` and so on...

Comment: Could you explain why the first line of your desired output is `1 2 0.4 3.5 4`? The first value in your vector is 3. The first line of `test[[2]]` is `0.1 3.9 3`. Apparently, 3 is the closest value to 3 and thus the first line should be `2 1 0.1 3.9 3`?

Comment: @ekoam Thanks for your question/comment. It´s because I´m looking for the closest value in the 2nd column (C2) of each data frame element in list. You´d be right if I were looking for `3` in the 3rd column (C3).

Comment: @HelioCamargo I see. So your desired output is based on the search through only the C2 column in each dataframe. You need some code that looks up only the column you specify. Am I right?

Comment: Ah, now it makes more sense :-) I guess @ekoam has sufficiently answered your question.

Comment: Thanks Dion and @ekoam and others for the interaction, ideas and answers! Thanks to you I was able to get going with my work. Cheers!

Comment: @ecoam Done! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach. We can generate the `list.index` and `line.number.in.df` for each dataframe and then `bind_rows` them together. Next, `slice` the rows where C2 contains the closest value for each number in that vector.

```
library(dplyr)

test <- list(structure(list(C1 = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.5), C2 = c(2, 3.5, 3.7
), C3 = c(0.3, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(C1 = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.6), C2 = c(3.9, 4.3, 
8), C3 = c(3, 5.2, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(C1 = c(0.4, 0.55, 0.8), C2 = c(8.9, 10.3, 
14), C3 = c(7, 8.4, 11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))

vector <- c(3, 14.4, 7, 0)

test %>% 
  lapply(tibble::rowid_to_column, "line.number.in.df") %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "list.index") %>% 
  slice(vapply(vector, \(x) which.min(abs(x - C2)), integer(1L)))
```

Output is

```
  list.index line.number.in.df  C1   C2   C3
1          1                 2 0.4  3.5  4.0
2          3                 3 0.8 14.0 11.0
3          2                 3 0.6  8.0 10.0
4          1                 1 0.2  2.0  0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could exploit the `substrings` of the `names`.

```
(w <- sapply(v, \(v) 
            names(which.min(abs(unlist(setNames(test, seq_along(test))) - v)))))
# [1] "2.C31" "3.C23" "3.C31" "2.C11"

t(mapply(\(x, y) c(list=x, line=y, test[[x]][y, ]), 
         as.numeric(substr(w, 1, 1)), as.numeric(substring(w, 5)))) |> 
  as.data.frame()
#   list line  C1  C2 C3
# 1    2    1 0.1 3.9  3
# 2    3    3 0.8  14 11
# 3    3    1 0.4 8.9  7
# 4    2    1 0.1 3.9  3
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
test <- list(structure(list(C1 = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.5), C2 = c(2, 3.5, 3.7
), C3 = c(0.3, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(C1 = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.6), C2 = c(3.9, 4.3, 
8), C3 = c(3, 5.2, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(C1 = c(0.4, 0.55, 0.8), C2 = c(8.9, 10.3, 
14), C3 = c(7, 8.4, 11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))

v <- c(3, 14.4, 7, 0)
```

Comment: Two completely different outputs (yours vs. mine). Now I am starting to question whether I have understood the OP’s desired output correctly haha :0

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. It finds the value in each of the columns per element of test, that is closest to the values in `vector`.

```
#install.packages('birk')
library(birk) # required for which.closest()

# find which of the values across the columns C1:C3 in each element of test are closest
# to the values of vector and return the corresponding row numbers
x <- sapply(1:length(vector), \(x) sapply(test, \(i) apply(i, 2, \(j) which.closest(j, vector[x]))))
x <- apply(x, 1, \(x) as.data.frame(table(x)))
x <- lapply(x, \(i) i[which.max(i[, 2]), ])
row_numbers_df <- as.numeric(matrix(do.call(rbind, x)[['x']]))

# extract the values in each of the column C1:C3 corresponding to row_numbers_df
vals <- array(0, dim = length(row_numbers_df))
for (i in 1:length(row_numbers_df)) { vals[i] <- do.call(cbind, test)[row_numbers_df[i], i] }

# how many columns does each data.frame embedded in test have?
unique_number_of_cols <- unique(sapply(test, ncol))

# store results in a data.frame
r <- \(x) round(x, 1)
out <- data.frame(
  seq_len(length(test)),
  r(rowMeans(matrix(row_numbers_df, ncol = unique_number_of_cols, byrow = TRUE))),
  matrix(vals, ncol = unique_number_of_cols, byrow = TRUE)
)
names(out) <- c('list.index', 'line.number.in.df', sapply(test, colnames)[, 1])
```

Result

```
> out
  list.index line.number.in.df  C1  C2 C3
1          1               3.0 0.5 3.7  5
2          2               1.7 0.6 3.9  3
3          3               1.7 0.8 8.9  7
```

Alternatively, if you really want to have each `line.number.in.df` per unique column, then you can easily store them as separate columns in `out`.

```
x <- sapply(1:length(vector), \(x) sapply(test, \(i) apply(i, 2, \(j) which.closest(j, vector[x]))))
x <- apply(x, 1, \(x) as.data.frame(table(x)))
x <- lapply(x, \(i) i[which.max(i[, 2]), ])
row_numbers_df <- as.numeric(matrix(do.call(rbind, x)[['x']]))
names(row_numbers_df) <- do.call(c, lapply(test, names))

row_numbers_df
vals <- array(0, dim = length(row_numbers_df))
for (i in 1:length(row_numbers_df)) { vals[i] <- do.call(cbind, test)[row_numbers_df[i], i] }

unique_number_of_cols <- unique(sapply(test, ncol))

out <- data.frame(
  seq_len(length(test)),
  split(row_numbers_df, names(row_numbers_df)),
  matrix(vals, ncol = unique_number_of_cols, byrow = TRUE)
)
column_names <- sapply(test, colnames)[, 1]
names(out) <- c('list.index',
                paste0('line.number.in.df.', column_names),
                column_names)
```

Result

```
> out
  list.index line.number.in.df.C1 line.number.in.df.C2 line.number.in.df.C3  C1  C2 C3
1          1                    3                    3                    3 0.5 3.7  5
2          2                    3                    1                    1 0.6 3.9  3
3          3                    3                    1                    1 0.8 8.9  7
```